# Eliminating duplicates from a COALESCED column in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, coalesce

I'm writing a stored procedure. The query that I'm using takes rows that are identical in every way except for 2 columns and combines them into one row and coalesces the two rows into one. Now I'm running into another issue. Sometimes there are duplicate values in those two rows and I want to eliminate the duplicates.

Example:

```
TeamID    Team    City     State    Equipment
1         Thunder OKC      OK       Basketball, Basketball, Basketball, Shorts, Jersey, Jersey
```

I want it to be like this:

```
TeamID    Team    City     State    Equipment
1         Thunder OKC      OK       Basketball, Shorts, Jersey
```

Here is the query that I'm using that combines the rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            AssignedOfficeID, AssignedOffice, OperatorID, OperatorName, RigMasterID, DrillerRigNumber, WellID,
            County, State, WellName, CompanyMan, CompanyManPhone, DateStart, DateStop, Representative, RepresentativeID, RepresentativeAssignedID, RepresentativeAssigned,
            PricePerDay, CotNumber, CustomerOrderTicketNumber,
            Equipment = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + COALESCE(RentalEquipmentAbbreviation, EquipmentAbbreviation, '')
                            FROM @ActiveRigsInfo AS ARI2
                            WHERE ARI2.AssignedOfficeID = ARI1.AssignedOfficeID AND ARI2.AssignedOfficeID = ARI1.AssignedOfficeID
                            AND ARI2.OperatorID = ARI1.OperatorID AND ARI2.OperatorName = ARI1.OperatorName
                            AND ARI2.RigMasterID = ARI1.RigMasterID AND ARI2.DrillerRigNumber = ARI1.DrillerRigNumber
                            AND ARI2.WellID = ARI1.WellID AND ARI2.County = ARI1.County AND ARI2.State = ARI1.State
                            AND ARI2.WellName = ARI1.WellName AND ARI2.CompanyMan = ARI2.CompanyMan AND ARI2.CompanyManPhone = ARI1.CompanyManPhone
                            AND ARI2.DateStart = ARI1.DateStart AND ARI2.Representative = ARI1.Representative
                            AND ARI2.CotNumber = ARI1.CotNumber  
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
                        FROM @ActiveRigsInfo AS ARI1   
                        ORDER BY AssignedOffice, OperatorID, RigMasterID;
```

Is there a way to do this when creating the stored procedure? Or is there a way that I can alter my query to do this?

All I want to do is take out the duplicates from the coalesced columns. The query does as expected except for that.

Thanks. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `DISTINCT` in your subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            AssignedOfficeID, AssignedOffice, OperatorID, OperatorName, RigMasterID, DrillerRigNumber, WellID,
            County, State, WellName, CompanyMan, CompanyManPhone, DateStart, DateStop, Representative, RepresentativeID, RepresentativeAssignedID, RepresentativeAssigned,
            PricePerDay, CotNumber, CustomerOrderTicketNumber,
            Equipment = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + COALESCE(RentalEquipmentAbbreviation, EquipmentAbbreviation, '')
                            FROM @ActiveRigsInfo AS ARI2
                            WHERE ARI2.AssignedOfficeID = ARI1.AssignedOfficeID AND ARI2.AssignedOfficeID = ARI1.AssignedOfficeID
                            AND ARI2.OperatorID = ARI1.OperatorID AND ARI2.OperatorName = ARI1.OperatorName
                            AND ARI2.RigMasterID = ARI1.RigMasterID AND ARI2.DrillerRigNumber = ARI1.DrillerRigNumber
                            AND ARI2.WellID = ARI1.WellID AND ARI2.County = ARI1.County AND ARI2.State = ARI1.State
                            AND ARI2.WellName = ARI1.WellName AND ARI2.CompanyMan = ARI2.CompanyMan AND ARI2.CompanyManPhone = ARI1.CompanyManPhone
                            AND ARI2.DateStart = ARI1.DateStart AND ARI2.Representative = ARI1.Representative
                            AND ARI2.CotNumber = ARI1.CotNumber  
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
                        FROM @ActiveRigsInfo AS ARI1   
                        ORDER BY AssignedOffice, OperatorID, RigMasterID;
```